# How to manage excel interop objects when working with excel cells

Tags: vb.net, excel-addins, addin-express

I am just starting with Excel Add-in express in visual studio and have read that an expression like  `mySheet.Columns.count`is a big "no-no" because it creates an intermediate object `Columns` that is not tied to any variable and cannot be later released.

With that in mind, I wrote the below code, carefully making sure that i don't chain any objects. This seems like a really time consuming way to code so wanted to sanity check my approach before progressing any further. Is there a better way?

```
'find ends
    Dim leftCol As Integer
    Dim tmpCell, tmpCell2 As Excel.Range
    tmpCell = Sh.Cells(1, 1) 'COM
    If (tmpCell.Value <> "") Then
        leftCol = 1
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tmpCell)
    Else
        tmpCell2 = tmpCell.End(XlDirection.xlToRight)
        leftCol = tmpCell2.Column
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tmpCell2)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tmpCell)
    End If
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Sh)
```

Comment: If you're using add-in express then the vsto tag should be removed, especially for this problem. VSTO handles the Office resources differently than other products, which directly affects any response to this question.

Comment: Well, the third line: `srcSh.Cells(mappingRow, 1)` (and you don't show us how srcSh is defined!) is creating an intermediate object (`Cells`)... So you don't handle that and other than that I don't see anything that could be chained?

Comment: calrified the code a little.  `Cells` is stored in the `tmpCell` and then released. in the if statement. Is that not enough?

Comment: If your concern is the chaining, then sh.Cells(1,1) is exactly the problem you're trying to avoid. You'd need: `Excel.Cells cells = sh.Cells : tmpCell = cells(1,1)`. Referencing an item in a collection using indexes on the collection is short-hand for something like: `Cells.Item(index)` - which makes the chaining more obvious, perhaps?

Comment: thanks. One more question: in a long method I will need to use temp com objects like `Cells` and `Columns` repeatedly. Do you recommend I assign these to variables and hold them for the duration of the routine, then release at the end? Maybe as big `try` ... `finally` statement? Or is it better to assign then quickly release, then create new variable when needed use, then release? Option one seems less laborious, would there be any downside to that approach?